# SQL Foreign Key across multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

I am modeling inspections. Inspection forms are arbitrary, and essentially are a list of fields.

```
CREATE TABLE InspectionForms
(
    InspectionFormId INT PRIMARY KEY,
    InspectionFormName NVARCHAR(64),

    ... (CreatorId, TimeCreated, etc.)
);
CREATE TABLE InspectionFormFields
(
    InspectionFormId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES InspectionForms,
    InspectionFormFieldId INT,
    FieldName NVARCHAR(64),
    PRIMARY KEY(InspectionFormId, InspectionFormFieldId)
);
```

So, with an InspectionForm named `Bathroom`, with fields for `Toilet`, `Shower`, and `Floor`, we would have values that look like this:

```
InspectionForms
---------------
0    Bathroom


InspectionFormFields
--------------------
0    0    Toilet
0    1    Shower
0    2    Floor
```

Then there are actual completed Inspections:

```
CREATE TABLE Inspections
(
    InspectionId INT PRIMARY KEY,
    InspectionFormId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES InspectionForms,

    ... (InspectorId, TimeOfInspection, etc.)
);

CREATE TABLE InspectionValues
(
    InspectionId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Inspections,
    InspectionFormFieldId INT,
    Rating TINYINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(InspectionId, InspectionFormFieldId)
);
```

Here are some sample values:

```
Inspections
-----------
0    0    ...


InspectionValues
----------------
0    0    5    (Inspection 0 scored a 5 in the Toilet)
0    1    3    (Inspection 0 scored a 3 in the Shower)
0    2    4    (Inspection 0 scored a 4 in the Floor)
```

**Here's the kicker:** I want `InspectionValues` to have a `FOREIGN KEY` referencing `InspectionFormFields`. But it doesn't have an `InspectionFormId` column. I can think of two theoretical solutions, but I don't know how to implement either one.

**Solution 1:** I could simply move the `InspectionFormId` column from `Inspections` to `InspectionValues`, and add my foreign key. That would make our table look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE InspectionValues
(
    InspectionId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Inspections,
    InspectionFormId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES InspectionForms,
    InspectionFormFieldId INT,
    Rating TINYINT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(InspectionId, InspectionFormId, InspectionFormFieldId),
    FOREIGN KEY(InspectionFormId, InspectionFormFieldId) REFERENCES InspectionFormFields
);
```

If I do this, I want to somehow enforce that all `InspectionValues` with a given `InspectionId` share a common value for `InspectionFormId` (i.e. I don't want an `Inspection` to span across multiple `InspectionForms`). An easy, efficient way to do this would be to make sure that on each update, this query doesn't return any rows:

```
SELECT InspectionId
FROM InspectionValues a
GROUP BY InspectionId
HAVING MIN(InspectionFormId) < MAX(InspectionFormId);
```

**Solution 2:** The `InspectionValues` table stores a reference to a specific `Inspection`, which in turn stores a reference to a specific `InspectionForm`. I could simply create a foreign key pairing `InspectionFormFields` with `InspectionValue`-`Inspection` combinations

If that is not possible, perhaps I could somehow enforce on every update that this query returns no rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM InspectionValues a
JOIN Inspections b ON a.InspectionId = b.InspectionId
JOIN InspectionForms c ON b.InspectionFormId = c.InspectionFormId
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM InspectionFormFields d
    WHERE a.InspectionFormFieldId = d.InspectionFormFieldId AND b.InspectionFormId = d.InspectionFormId
);
```

I'm using SQL Server 2014, and don't need to support any other version of SQL. What's the right thing to do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should  leave InspectionFormId in the Inspections table (rather then move it  as you suggest).  Since InspectionId  is the primary key you cannot have only one inspectionformid per inspectionid.

```
CREATE TABLE Inspections
(
InspectionId INT PRIMARY KEY,
InspectionFormId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES InspectionForms,
);
```

Then add the inspectionformid to the inspectionvalues table:

```
CREATE TABLE InspectionValues
(
InspectionId INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Inspections,
InspectionFormId INT,
InspectionFormFieldId INT,
Rating TINYINT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(InspectionId, InspectionFormId, InspectionFormFieldId),
FOREIGN KEY(InspectionFormId, InspectionFormFieldId) 
       REFERENCES InspectionFormFields(InspectionFormId, InspectionFormFieldId)
```

);

In your solution1 above, InspectionValues you  had two foreign  keys containing InspectionFormId,  but you only need the multi-column one as show above.

Comment: What enforces that the `InspectionFormId` column in both the `Inspections` and `InspectionValues` tables share values, given a common `InspectionId`?

Comment: As it stands  now, you  don't even need the Inspections table.  However if you add a field like TimeOfInspection, or  Inspector, then you will need that table. In any case, to answer you question, the  application inserting data needs to  make sure that inspectionid's match between the Inspections table and the InspectionValues table.

Comment: @TimCooke: In `Inspections`, you could add `UNIQUE (InspectionId, InspectionFormId)`. Then the reference from `InspectionValues` to `Inspections` would take the form of `FOREIGN KEY (InspectionId, InspectionFormId) REFERENCES Inspections (InspectionId, InspectionFormId)`.

Comment: @AndriyM   the inspectionid is a primary key of inspections so added a unique key on (inspectionid, inspectionformid) is redundant and unnecessary

Comment: @danb: Yes, you are right, that is a redundancy. Sometimes redundancies are needed to solve non-trivial problems.

Comment: @AndriyM  not seeing how that adds any value